# Error while inserting image in database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle9i

Executing below programs is giving me error as,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
    at ImageStore.main(ImageStore.java:28)
```

I'm using ojdbc14.jar and my Oracle version is 9.0.1.1.1

```
public class ImageStore {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    Connection con = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
                    "usrname", "password");

String sql="update items set image=? where id=1";
    //String sql="select * from price";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    File f=new File("E:/Images/s.jpg");
    InputStream fos= new FileInputStream(f);

    ps.setBlob(1, fos);

    ps.execute();
    /*while(rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
*/
    ps.close();
    con.close();


}
```

}

Please help

Comment: Add (or link to) the full error log, please. Not just the line you think is the right one.

Comment: what version of JRE are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I had to insert image also in a database and the way it worked was the following

1. Convert the image to an array of Byte
2. Use setBinaryStream where data is an array of Byte

   preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(1,new ByteArrayInputStream(data),data.length);

**EDIT:** The downfall of this technique is that the integer limitation size for an array

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractMethodError` suggests that you are not working with the proper driver. If you are using java5 or above, try downloading the appropriate ojdbc driver (ojdbc14.jar is for java1.4)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-111060-084321.html

Comment: I compiled my program with jdk1.3, 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 . but with all of those I'm getting the error.

Comment: Can you post the classpath for both compilation and execution? Also try compiling and running your class with ojdbc6.jar using jre6.